# Why is this not an example of recursion?

Tags: recursion

So, I saw someplace (I'm not sure where off the top of my head, but if I recall it I will post a link to it) that the following code was not example of recursion:

```
void f() {
    f();
}
```

Now, this is a function that calls itself (albeit, infinitely). Why would that not be an example of recursion? It might not be the best example, but why would they go so far as stating that it's not recursion at all?

Comment: It is recursive...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's definitely an example of a recursive function, based solely on the definition of "recursive". Simply speaking, a recursive function is any one that calls itself.

It's hard to explain why someone said it wasn't without seeing their claim in context (and hopefully an attempt at a justification for that claim).

That said, it's not a very *useful* recursive function, and perhaps that was the point they were driving at. Any program that calls that function will eventually crash after it overflows the stack. Sometimes, this is called a "Stack Overflow" error. :-)

*Useful* recursive functions have to contain some kind of conditional code that causes the recursion to stop eventually.

Comment: Of course there are also useful recursive functions that don't have a base case. For example the infinite loop in a pure functional language. Proper tail call optimization will prevent a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your code example does not have a way to terminate and would go on forever, likely causing a stack overflow exception. Recursive functions have a simple way to terminate through a base case condition. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) article for a proper definition and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely recursion, and here are some notes form the University of Wisconsin-Madison. Actually using `void f()` as the example http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/6.RECURSION.html

The site could of been trying to drive home a point of how not to do recursion .. not sure without the source link.

Answer (score 1):

It is example of recursion but there is no way to end it , you have to terminate it using  condition.